# Check/verify decryption secret for OpenSSL

Tags: unix, encryption, openssl, cryptography

On a unix system, I encrypt a file `file1` using OpenSSL AES-256-CBC: `openssl aes-256-cbc -a -salt -in file1 -out file1.enc -k secret`

The decryption is done via `openssl aes-256-cbc -d -a -in file1.enc -out file1.dec -k secret`

**Is there a way to verify that, before actually starting the decryption process, the secret is correct?**

My research has not shown any helpful results so far.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Answer (score 1):

If all you have is the encrypted data it is impossible to determine if the key is correct prior to decryption. It is also impossible to determine if the key was correct after decryption other than by examining that the data make sense, is what you expect.

You would have to add some other method to determine if the key is the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is a check for integrity and/or authenticity. AES in CBC mode does not provide these features, only plain encryption/decryption.

If you need it you should switch from CBC to GCM mode. It provides authenticity and integrity check while decrypting. Therefore if the decryption succeeds you are sure that the decryption result is correct.

Answer (score 0):

If this is your entire system, then no, OpenSSL does not have any mechanism to check the password prior to decryption (or in many cases even after decryption). You can build such a system, however, and can even build it out of OpenSSL if you're restricted to that.

If we were building it out of OpenSSL, then the absolute simplest way to solve it is to just encrypt some know piece of data with the same password. Glue the encrypted known-plaintext and the encrypted actual-plaintext together. You can glue them together many ways; the simplest in commandline form would be to stick them in separate files and then `tar` them together.

When you're ready to decrypt, tear them back apart, and try to decrypt the known-plaintext. If it decrypts correctly, then you're golden and you can decrypt your real data.

OpenSSL does not have a particularly strong KDF, so this approach can make brute-force password cracking a bit easier (though no easier than if your file has some known header).

This doesn't ensure that the ciphertext is unchanged, however. An attacker could still have modified it and OpenSSL won't always know. There are ways to fix that problem by modifying the format further, but again openssl doesn't provide any direct way that I'm aware of. The best approach here would depend on your exact constraints.